# A centered search box + buttons that grows and shrinks with max width and no wrap

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck getting this HTML/CSS to work.

I have 3 inputs, with a search box and 2 buttons. I want the search box to grow to a max width of something like 400px when the browser is wide enough to handle it, but also shrink down to fit 100% of the width minus the width of the 2 buttons for stuff like mobile browsers. I don't want the buttons to wrap.

Here's what I want:

Desktop/large display:

```
|                                                          |
|            SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS A B            |
|                                                          |
```

Mobile/small display:

```
|                  |
| SSSSSSSSSSSS A B |
|                  |
```

Here's what I've got so far. With the div method, the combined width of the buttons isn't taken into account and they scroll off the page when the browser is shrunk. The table method is close, but the buttons hug the right hand side of the browser when the browser is enlarged.

div:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .search {
            text-align: center;
            padding:5px;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div id="SearchDiv" class="search">
    <input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
    speech="" style="width:100%;max-width:400px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" id="FindButton" style="" />
    <input type="submit" value="More" id="MoreButton" style="" />
  </div>
</html>
```

table:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .search {
        text-align: center;
        padding:5px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <table class="search" align="center" width="100%"
  cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
        speech="" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Find" id="FindButton" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="More" id="MoreButton" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Zhihao Jia's suggestion (not working correctly)

div:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .search {
            text-align: center;
            padding:5px;
            white-space:nowrap;
            max-width:400px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <div id="SearchDiv" class="search">
    <input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
    speech="" style="width:100%;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" id="FindButton" style="" />
    <input type="submit" value="More" id="MoreButton" style="" />
  </div>
</html>
```

table:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .search {
        text-align: center;
        padding:5px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <table class="search" width="100%"
  cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
        speech="" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;" />
      </td>
      <td align="left">
        <input type="submit" value="Find" id="FindButton" />
        <input type="submit" value="More" id="MoreButton" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the div method, you can have the width of the buttons taken into account by setting the max-width on the div (the containing element) instead of the textbox.

For the table method, you can avoid having the buttons hug the right by putting both buttons in one td, then then setting align=left on the button td and align=right on the textbox td. You also need to remove width=100% from the textbox td. Something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
    speech="" style="width:100%;max-width:400px;" />
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="submit" value="Find" id="FindButton" />
    <input type="submit" value="More" id="MoreButton" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not getting good results with that.

With the div method now, the whole thing is left aligned and the buttons still become obscured.

With the table, without setting the textbox width to 100%, it doesn't expand when enlarging the browser. Either way, the functionality is pretty good, but the end result isn't exactly centered. I updated my original post with what I have using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the problem,try the following solution -

Pasting only the changed code -

```
<div id="SearchDiv" class="search"style="min-width:480px;" >
<input type="text" id="SearchTextBox" x-webkit-speech=""
speech="" style="width:70%;min-width:100px" />
```

[**Full Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QRNcx/)

Note: If the content has no room to fit into the display available - it **WILL** go out of view, but still be visible via scroll. So,play with the width's to get the display optimised. I'm not sure that you can keep the search bar in place with a given width and expect the buttons also to remain in the same view when they dont have any room to stay in the current view.